# Multiple returns in the same function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to display two results inside the same function, the code that I am writing is as follows:

```
myFun <- function(x,y,z){
  sum1 <- x+y
  print("The first sum is:")
  return(sum1)

  sum2 <- y+z
  print("The second sum is:")
  return(sum2)

}
```

However, I only get the sum1 as the output. After that, the sum2 block is never executed.

The result I got is :

```
> myFun(2,3,4)
[1] "The first sum is:"
[1] 5
>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: `return(list(sum1, sum2))`. The first `return` breaks out of the function. If you want to compute both, only use one return statement at the end, or to print, return `f(paste, sum1, sum2`) where `f` is just some function which defines the print return format

Comment: The issue is that as soon as you call return, the function is over with. If your language supports arrays, you could return an array of both return values. `return([sum1, sum2])`

Comment: @Pachonk the language is R.

Comment: @AkhilNair Thanks a lot. Your suggestion worked. Make your comment an answer, as it is a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from my comment above

The first `return` breaks out of the function. If you want to execute and return both statements, only use one return statement at the end, such as
`return(list(sum1, sum2))`
or to print, return 
`f(paste, sum1, sum2)`
where `f` is just some function which defines the print return format.

Answer (score 1):

```
myFun <- function(x,y,z){
 sum1 <- x+y
print("The first sum is:")

sum2 <- y+z
print("The second sum is:")
return(sum2)

}
```

return(variable) returns the variable and exits.
 Try  the above one.